# The same Java-source leading to various results

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm trying to learn Java and want to program a GUI. Trying to start with a simple calculator I ran into a problem while experimenting with JTextField. Compiling the following code sometimes results in an empty frame and sometimes in one with the panel and buttons in it.

This happens no matter if I use javac or eclipse.
I use the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;



public class Mainframe extends JFrame {

private JButton button1;
private JPanel mainpanel;
private JLabel headline;
private Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
JTextField number1;
JTextField number2;


public Mainframe(String s) {

    super(s);
    setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    mainpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(100, 100));
    number1 = new JTextField(20);
    number2 = new JTextField(20);
    headline = new JLabel("Simple Calculator");
    button1 = new JButton("1");

    mainpanel.add(headline, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainpanel.add(number1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    mainpanel.add(button1, BorderLayout.EAST);
    mainpanel.add(number2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainpanel.validate();

    getContentPane().add(mainpanel);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mainframe mainframe1 = new Mainframe("Title");

}
}
```

I want to repeat: This is not about differences between javac and eclipse but about a problem/occurence I have with both compilers - sometimes the result is as wanted, sometimes not. Why does that happen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the call to `JFrame.setVisible(true)` is the last line you invoke.

So just move the line:

```
setVisible(true);
```

to the end of your constructor.

A few more remarks:

- Don't extend if not needed (here it is not needed)
- Make sure that all the UI-related operations are done on the EDT (use a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` block to start your UI)
- Don't call `setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);` but `frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` to make a window take the whole screen space. Consider also calling `pack()` before making the frame visible (but before calling `frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`) so that all components are properly laid out and this will also set the size of the frame to its computed preferred size.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works for me. I don't understand the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` part - where should I put this? Does it ensure everything is done on the EDT?

Comment: @Paul Yes it ensures that the code within the provided `Runnable` is run on the EDT. Usually you put that in your `main` method. If you are looking for an example, check out the bottom of the code provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971633/how-to-reset-graphics-with-paintcomponent-on-transperant-jframe/15972416#15972416), don't mind the rest of it.

Answer (score 3):

Move your `setVisible( true )` to a moment where you have added all your components.

If you do not do this, you need to re-validate the layout as indicated in the javadoc of the [`Container#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) method:

> This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy. If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to display the added component.